# Formula y = mx + b en NASM

Tags: ensamblador, nasm

soy nuevo en ensamblador y estoy tratando de hacer esta ecuación y=mx+b en NASM, m y b tienen valores preestablecidos y x se de debe pedir al usuario, cuando coloco como entrada 7, el resultado debe dar 75, sin embargo me esta dando caracteres al azar, no se por qué pasa esto, si me podrían ayudar, no se si es al momento de imprimir o cuando realizo las operaciones aritméticas hay algún error

Para compilar uso estos comandos:
nasm -F dwarf -f elf64 ecuacion.asm && ld ecuacion.o -o ecuacion
./ecuacin

```
%macro print 2      ; Definición de macro con nombre imprimir que recibe dos parámetros
    mov eax,4       ; Llamada al sistema para escritura
    mov ebx,1       ; Estandar para salida de datos
    mov ecx,%1      ; El primer valor del macro es el mensaje que se va a imprimir, almacena en registro ecx 
    mov edx,%2      ; El segundo valor es la longitud  del mensaje a imprimir, almacena en registro edx
    int 80H         ; Interrupción del sitema   
%endmacro


section .data                               ; Seccion de datos
    mensaje1 db "Ingrese X: ",10,13         ; Mensaje que se quiere imprimir
    len1 equ $-mensaje1                     ; Longitud del mensaje
    
    mensaje2 db "El resultado es: "         ; Mensaje que se quiere imprimir
    len2 equ $-mensaje2                     ; Longitud del mensaje

    M dd 10                                 ; Constante de la ecuación con valor 10
    B dd 5                                  ; Constante de la ecuación con valor 5

section .bss                ; Seccion de datos no inicializados
    X resb 4                ; Variable con memoria reservada
    Y resb 4                ; Variable con memoria reservada
    input_size equ $-Y
    
section .text               ; Seccion de codigo
    global _start           ; Etiqueta predetermminada que indica donde inicia el programa

_start:                     ; Etiqueta de inicio

;*****Imprime el mensaje para ingresar valor de X*****
print mensaje1,len1
    
mov eax, 3                  ; Llamada al sistema para lectura
mov ebx, 0                  ; Estandar para entrada de datos
mov ecx, X                  ; Almacenar el valor en ecx
mov edx, 10
int 80h                     ; Interrupcion del sistema


;*****Hacer la multiplicacion*****
xor eax,eax
mov edx,0
mov eax,[M]
mov ebx,[X]


mul ebx                     ; Multiplicacion
add ebx, [B] 

mov [Y],ebx


print mensaje2,len2

print Y,input_size

end:
mov eax,1                   ; Salida el sistema
mov ebx,0                   ; Estado de salida
int 80h                     ; Interrupcion del sistema
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los registros que comienzan por **e** son 32 bits (4 bytes) (eax, ebx, ...). Mejor si los operandos coinciden con el tamaño de los registros. Puedes hacerlo reservando más memoria por ejemplo `M dd 10` o `X resb 4`. No olvides establecer `edx` en 0 antes de multiplicar ¿Por qué restas `30h` a la multiplicación? Y la syscall para escribir en consola escribe caracteres. Por lo tanto necesitas convertir el número en una secuencia de caracteres.

Comment: @Mateo con la reste de 30h estaba tratando de convertir el numero ingresado por syscall a entero

Comment: Bien, no recordaba que 30 en hexadecimal era el 0. Por favor no borres tu código. No podemos ayudarte sin él.